# How can I fail the build based on based on chutzpah coverage?

Tags: build-process, cruisecontrol.net, chutzpah

I've feel like I've tried everything we currently have a solution that upon checkin to TFS we force a build on CruiseControl.net. In our solution we use the Chutzpah JS Test Adapter.  We were able to successfully use the Chutzpah.console.exe to fail the build if any of the JS tests fails, now we would like to fail the build on the coverage. I cannot find any way to have Chutzpah.console.exe output coverage to the XML file it generates.

I thought I could solve the problem by writing my own .xsl that would parse _Chutzpha.coverage.html. I was going to convert that to xml using the junit format that CruiseControl already can interpret. Since I just care about failing the build I was going to make the output of my transform just look like more unit tests that failed. in the xsl i would set the attribute failures > 0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<testsuites>
  <testsuite name="c:\build\jstest\jstest\tests\TestSpec2.js" tests="1" failures="1">
    <testcase name="Coverage" time="46" />
  </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

But I really can't since the incoming html has self closing tags.

So, now I want to just run Chutzpah.Console.exe and pipe the output to a file, because the console output does display the total average coverage, read that value, and fail the build if it drops below a threshold.

Is there a better option? Am I missing soemthing? I don't know that much about cruisecontrol.net

Comment: Chutzpah has a setting called CodeCoverageSuccessPercentage (https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah/wiki/Chutzpah.json-Settings-File) that determines what percentage of line covered chutzpah will consider success. It currently doesn't cause a non-zero status code though because of this. Would making that change solve your issue?

Comment: I think that might. I really don't know much about how chutzpah and cruisecontrol.net interact

Comment: Actually that is exactly what we need. If the coverage was output to an xml file like you do with the unit test data, we could write an xsl file to transform it how we need in to cruise control.

Answer (score 1):

I think the output to a file, and parse that is the only option left.
A pity that the coverage info is not in the xml file :-(

This is in fact more a problem with Chutzpah than with CCNet,
think of CCNet as an upgraded task scheduler, it has a lot of options, but relies on the input it receives from the called program. If that one can not provide the data, you're stuck with these kind of workarounds :-(

Answer (score 0):

There is another option, but it may be more of a trip than you're interested in embarking upon.  [Sonarqube](http://www.sonarqube.org/) is a server based tool for managing and analyzing code quality.  It has a plugin called "Build Breaker", which allows you to fail the build if any number of code quality metrics are not met, including unit test coverage.  Like I said, it's kind of involved because you have to set up a server and learn this new tool, but it's good to have anyway.

I use Chutzpah with the /lcov command line option so that it outputs the coverage to a file, then tell sonar to find the coverage in that file in the sonar configuration for that project.  Then, you add a step to your cruise control.net build process to run the sonar analysis, and if you have configured your build breaker plugin right, it will fail the build in cruise control if the coverage is not at the level you specified.